# Difference between [:alpha:] class and [a-zA-Z]; Is [:alpha:] OS independent?

Tags: r, regex

I had always heard that the `[:alpha:]` character class was equivalent to `[A-Za-z]` but in the output below this does not seem to be the case regardless if I use `gsub` (with and without `perl = TRUE`) or `stringi`.  It seems `[:alpha:]` matches non-ascii characters but I may be misunderstanding.  Using `?regex` tells me:

> Certain named classes of characters are predefined. Their interpretation depends on the locale (see locales); the interpretation below is that of the POSIX locale.

But I still don't get the difference.  To me `[A-Za-z]` matches exactly 52 characters, while `[:alpha:]` matches way more.

**Questions**

1. What is the difference between `[:alpha:]` class and `[a-zA-Z]`
2. What exactly will `[:alpha:]` match?
3. Will `[:alpha:]` work the same across different operating systems and locations around the world?

```
x <- c(
    "danish characteøs  sentåment æcores words correctly 456",
    "It works with probleme but not with problème 234"
)

gsub("[[:alpha:] ]",  '', x)
## "456" "234"

gsub("[a-zA-Z ]",  '', x)
## [1] "øåæ456" "è234"

stringi::stri_replace_all_regex(x, "[[:alpha:] ]",  '')
## "456" "234"

stringi::stri_replace_all_regex(x, "[a-zA-Z ]",  '')
## [1] "øåæ456" "è234"
```

Comment: A-Z covers the letters between A and Z which is every letter in the English alphabet, the examples above use an extend character set.  Where does è fall?  Not between a-z thus why alpha is needed.

Comment: And into the wilds [perllocale](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.30.0/perllocale), which upon close read in conjunction with POSIX shows both tests and vagaries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. `[:alpha:]` stands for "alphabetic characters:". `[:alpha:]`, as in the opposite to `[:digit:]`. This includes literally every letter character in your character encoding. Whereas `[a-zA-Z]` is capturing any character between the symbol 'a' and 'z', as well as 'A' and 'Z'. As @Charles Duffy noted the locale order of these can differ and so other characters *can* be contained. In standard English UTF-8, however, this will only include standard English letters (26 letters * 2 lower & upper case = 52), and thus will not include any letter from other languages, e.g., é, ö, ï, etc.
2. `[:alpha:]` will match all alphabetic characters.
3. Yes, since `[:alpha:]` matches all alphabetic characters it will work the same across different languages, operations systems or locations.

To give more context, the `regex` function implemented  in R (used by  `grepl`, `regexpr`, `gregexpr`, `sub` or `gsub`, among others) follows the POSIX 1003.2 standard. This means matching is based on:

> the bit pattern used for encoding the character, not on the graphic
> representation of the character.

Below is an example of variations of different language characters for `Sys.getlocale(category = "LC_ALL")` "en_GB.UTF-8":

```
fr_chr <- "Voix ambiguë d’un cœur qui au zéphyr préfère les jattes de kiwi."
ge_chr <- "Fix, Schwyz! quäkt Jürgen blöd vom Paß."
gr_chr <- "Ταχίστη αλώπηξ βαφής ψημένη γη, δρασκελίζει υπέρ νωθρού κυνός."
en_chr <- "Shaw, those twelve beige hooks are joined if I patch a young, gooey mouth."
cn_chr <- "敏捷的棕色狐狸跨过懒狗"

gsub("[[:alpha:]]","",fr_chr)
[1] "  ’         ."
gsub("[[:alpha:]]","",ge_chr)
[1] ", !     ."
gsub("[[:alpha:]]","",gr_chr)
[1] "    ,    ."
gsub("[[:alpha:]]","",en_chr)
[1] ",           ,  ."
gsub("[[:alpha:]]","",cn_chr)
[1] ""

gsub("[A-Za-z]","",fr_chr)
[1] " ë ’ œ   é éè    ."
gsub("[A-Za-z]","",ge_chr)
[1] ", ! ä ü ö  ß."
gsub("[A-Za-z]","",gr_chr)
[1] "Ταχίστη αλώπηξ βαφής ψημένη γη, δρασκελίζει υπέρ νωθρού κυνός."
gsub("[A-Za-z]","",en_chr)
[1] ",           ,  ."
gsub("[A-Za-z]","",cn_chr)
[1] "敏捷的棕色狐狸跨过懒狗"
```

Comment: `[a-z]` _can_ contain other characters, depending on the locale's collation/ordering rules. Whether it will or won't, though is certainly not a thing to bet on.